# android nullpointerexception in function

Tags: android

I'm new to Java/android so a lot of these terms are foreign but am willing to learn.  I'm not gonna go into detail on the app as I dont think it's relevant.  My issue as it stands, I've used tutorials and pieces of code from a blog and have gotten my code to work.  Trying to clean up and organize my code I get a nullpoiner exception when I move one line (creating my autocompletetextview).  Below is the code I've used.  My 1 line of code that's giving me an issue is

**AutoCompleteTextView companyAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) addAddressDialog.findViewById(R.id.add_record_dialog_autocomplete);**

When I move it to right under the start of my function it errors out but when left in place it works like a charm.  I'd like to understand why this is.

```
public void addAddress() {
    final Dialog addAddressDialog = new Dialog(this);
    final int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
    final String[] from = new String[] { "CompanyName" };

    // Create a SimpleCursorAdapter for the CompanyName field.
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter =  new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout. select_dialog_item, null, from, to);

    addAddressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_record_dialog);
    addAddressDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.add_record_dialog_address_title));
    addAddressDialog.setCancelable(true);

    final EditText text1 = (EditText) addAddressDialog.findViewById(R.id.add_record_dialog_edittext);
    text1.setHint(getString(R.string.add_record_dialog_company_hint));

    Button buttonOK1 = (Button) addAddressDialog.findViewById(R.id.add_record_dialog_ok);
    buttonOK1.setText(getString(R.string.add_record_dialog_ok_button));

    Button buttonCancel1 = (Button) addAddressDialog.findViewById(R.id.add_record_dialog_cancel);
    buttonCancel1.setText(getString(R.string.add_record_dialog_cancel_button));

    buttonOK1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle addressBundle = new Bundle();
            addressBundle.putString("CompanyName", text1.getText().toString());

            Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, AddAddressActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(addressBundle);
            startActivity(intent);

            addAddressDialog.dismiss();
        }   
    });

    buttonCancel1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cancel button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            addAddressDialog.dismiss();
        }   
    });
    AutoCompleteTextView companyAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) addAddressDialog.findViewById(R.id.add_record_dialog_autocomplete);

    companyAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Set an OnItemClickListener, to update dependent fields when
    // a choice is made in the AutoCompleteTextView.
    companyAutoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
            // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the
            // result set
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Get the CompanyID from this row in the database.
            String companyID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));

            // test to make sure CompanyID returned
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), companyID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Set the CursorToStringConverter, to provide the labels for the
    // choices to be displayed in the AutoCompleteTextView.
    adapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new CursorToStringConverter() {
        public String convertToString(android.database.Cursor cursor) {
            // Get the label for this row out of the "CompanyName" column
            final int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("CompanyName");
            final String str = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            return str;
        }
    });

    // Set the FilterQueryProvider, to run queries for choices
    // that match the specified input.
    adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            Cursor cursorReturn = dbAdapter.getCompanies(constraint != null ? constraint.toString() : null);

            startManagingCursor(cursorReturn);
            return cursorReturn;
        }
        });

    addAddressDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you call `setContentView` later.

`setContentView` sets up the layout for the `addAddressDialog` dialog. If you don't call `setContentView`, it has no layout items, therefore `addAddressDialog.findViewById(...);` will be `null`, and, obviously you cannot cast that to anything, nor can you call `setHint` on it.

It shouldn't matter where this line of code is in your method, as long as your line with `setContentView` is called **before** it.

Comment: Well that makes sense.  Thank you for the info.  I'm so used to VB and not needing to worry about the UI.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that matters is that your `findViewById()` call is called after the call to `setContentView()`, i.e. this line:

```
addAddressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_record_dialog);
```

The XML file `add_record_dialog.xml` is the View hierarchy that you are traversing to find the view with the ID of `add_record_dialog_autocomplete`. Until you've given the dialog that view hierarchy, it cannot traverse it, hence you'll be getting a `NullPointerException` when you try to use your `AutoCompleteTextView` since it cannot find your view.

EDIT: Also, if you mean you placed it at the VERY start of the method, that will also fail due to the fact that `addAddressDialog` will be null until your call to

```
final Dialog addAddressDialog = new Dialog(this);
```